# PHP, MySQL, and Google Maps API Generate POI by City and State Name?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am building an application which will utilize the Google Maps JavaScript API v3. I have a listing of locations in a MySQL database stored by City and State (my application does not require any more precision than that), and I would like to use the API to plot these points on the map.

[This tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3) shows how this can be done if you have the longitude and latitude points you would like to plot.

My question is, before I spend a bunch of time seeing if this will work, does anyone know if Google Maps will be able to plot the points by `<City>, <State>`, since I do not have the longitudinal and latitudinal points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use the geocoding API to get the latitude and longitude in order to display a point.

I did this for a real estate site I built.

Refer to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/ for API documentation

Comment: So... basically, before my City and State was stored in the DB, I would use the send these values to the Geocoding API, and then store the latitude and longitude values which are returned, or could the Google Maps API use the City and State name to retrieve the lat/long at runtime?

Comment: you can geocode it right before you want to display the point, however I recommend storing the values for load time efficiency and accuracy. The maps API will ignore invalid "," locations but still leaves empty code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can even use the [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) so that you can get the latitude and longitude and then plot it that way.

Comment: You would have to send the URL with the city, state that you want, and then you can specify if you want the response in xml or json and then you can grab the lat/long from that response.